# How to stop LVT movement

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I’ve installed some Luxury Vinyl Tiles inside my porch. It’s a click together type of tile. No adhesive needed and it has a 1mm underlay (as recommended).

It has the recommended expansion gap around the whole perimeter. However, when (for example) a frustrated wife struggles to get a pram through the house, the tiles all move up to the top expansion gap leaving no expansion gap at the top - and a big gap at the bottom.

I have yet to put skirting board on but I have my doubts that this will significantly reduce the amount of movement.

Should I not have bought LVTs for such a small space? Shall I glue them down? Shall I fill the expansion gap?

NOTE - This is for a porch in the UK. Which is might be quite different from a porch in the US (if you’re thinking of something like Gilmore Girls). It’s a much smaller space.

Comment: Most floors that are hard require a good flat base/sub floor.  Movement usually means the sub floor was not flat, has dips, or is weak, it bounces when walking on it.

Comment: And it needs adhesive.

Comment: Do not glue them down, as then when they expand/contract they will bulge or pull apart at the joins. Sounds like the problem is floor or underlayment is too slippery. Is the underlayment pre-attached, or something from a different company?

Comment: Any idea if the tiles are slipping over underlayment or if underlayment is slipping over floor below?

Comment: What are the approximate dimensions of the patio and of one tile?

Comment: @Armand what if the center tile was glued down—that would allow for expansion, but not translation.

Comment: @Huesmann Yes that sounds like a good idea if it's big enough to provide a solid anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting rubber in the expansion space then applying the skirting board so the tiles are always jammed against the rubber and not able to ride up above or down under the rubber.

The rubber will still allow expansion but will hopefully force the tiles back to center, or not allow them to slide from center if the rubber can put enough pressure on the tiles.

Comment: What about silicone?

Comment: Good question. My idea comes from the rubber spacers put in 5-piece stile/rail/panel cabinet doors, where the center panel is a large plate of solid wood, and space needs to be allowed for seasonal expansion/contraction. The spacers make the panel remain centered in the door. I don't know how silicone would work in such a situation.